# Operations with Dates (Subtract)

Tags: r, date, datetime, data.table

I have  a column with dates:

```
  Time
1/1/2005
2/1/2005
3/1/2005
4/1/2005
```

How can I subtract one month from each date?

Comment: This means you want Feb-28-2014 to go back to Jan-28-2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to `POSIXlt` and subtract one from the `mon` attribute

```
(x <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(df$Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y")))
# [1] "2005-01-01 UTC" "2005-02-01 UTC" "2005-03-01 UTC" "2005-04-01 UTC"
x$mon <- x$mon - 1
x
# [1] "2004-12-01 UTC" "2005-01-01 UTC" "2005-02-01 UTC" "2005-03-01 UTC"
```

Another option is to use `lubridate`

```
date <- as.Date(df$Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
library(lubridate)
month(date) <- month(date) - 1
date
# [1] "2004-12-01" "2005-01-01" "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01"
```

where `df` is

```
structure(list(Time = c("1/1/2005", "2/1/2005", "3/1/2005", "4/1/2005"
)), .Names = "Time", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I make output (using `POSIXlt`) in format like 12/1/2004 ?

Comment: Right! But it shows me 12/01/2004 but I need 12/1/2004 (the same as in my question)

Comment: @user45415631 You can try `gsub("0?(.*/)0(.*/)","\\1\\2", format(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))`